# Permission error when uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the following code:

```
var saveFolder = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.DropBoxFolder, guid.ToString("N"));

// Create folder, if it does not exist (for the first attachment, it shouldn't exist)
if (!Directory.Exists(saveFolder))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(saveFolder);
}

var saveFilePath = Path.Combine(saveFolder, file.FileName);

file.SaveAs(saveFilePath);
```

I'm using GUIDs to generate folders for uploads on my IIS server. The .NET web application is configured to impersonate the user. I granted modify permissions to the target folder (it is a local path on the web server) for Domain Users, Local Service and Everyone, but some users still can't upload files. I can and other people on my team can.

The weird part is that the exception says this:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\USERID\Desktop\FILENAME'

That path is the path to the file the user selected to upload (their local file path). I feel it is safe to say that the user has permission to his own file on his own desktop. I don't use user impersonation much, so I am wondering what I missed in my configuration or permissions. Any suggestions for debugging this issue? Thanks!

Note: the CreateDirectory method works just fine, even when the exception is thrown. I would have thought that if the user didn't have permission the directory creation would have failed first.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but you might want to check the ownership of the created directory. It's possible that you do have permissions to create the directory, but if the ownership is not right on the created  directory, then you would no longer have permission to write into that.

Comment: That's the hard part. I can't figure out how to check the ownership of a Windows folder. When I googled it, most web sites said that if I have some auditing turned on, I could see it, but, normally, you can't see folder owners. Do you know a way?

Comment: Blarg! I've double-checked everything! Why isn't this working??